# カラー画像認識の画像管理ライブラリはありますか

Tags: spresense

SPRESENSEで画像認識の機能を実装しており、Arduino IDEのサンプルスケッチnumber_recognition.inoにはNetPBM.h のモノクロ PBMファイルの画像ライブラリ使っています。

もしNeural Network Consoleで学習された3(RBG)x100x100ピクセル入力のクラス分類ネットワークをSPRESENSEに実装したいなら、dnnrt.inputVariable の inputはどうしたらいいですか。

どう考えても、カラー(JPG)画像のライブラリがないとできないようです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

DNN の画像認識に使う画像データは、JPGではなくRGBのRAWデータを使う必要があります。JPGは圧縮率や画像のささいな違いによって全く異なるデータ列になりますので認識用にも学習用にも使えません。

**1) SPRESENSEのカメラで取得したデータを認識用データとして使いたい場合**
この場合、カメラ画像をRGBへ変換する必要がありますが、その処理は次のスライドの13～15ページが参考になると思います。

https://www.slideshare.net/YoshinoriOota/spresense-study-meeting1-how-to-use-the-camera-board

この例ではYUVからYのデータだけを抜いていますが、このルーチンでYUV->RGB変換をすればカラー画像の入力データとして使えます。

**2) SPRESENSEのカメラで取得したデータを学習用データとして使いたい場合**
PNM(NetPBM)フォーマットは非常に簡単なので自作することが簡単にできます。

https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/PNM_(%E7%94%BB%E5%83%8F%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9E%E3%83%83%E3%83%88)

カメラで取得したデータをSDカードにPNMフォーマットで記録し、PC上でImageMagikなどを使ってPNGに変換すればNNCの学習用データとして活用できます。

以上、ご参考になれば。