# SpresenseのHDRカメラで撮影されたraw画像の取得方法

Tags: spresense

SpresenseのHDRカメラで撮影されたraw画像を取得する方法を知りたいです。コード付きで説明して頂けると助かります。

Comment: `12bit諧調のrowデータ`というのは`RGB`or`RGB565`のことでしょうか？ [製品仕様](https://developer.sony.com/ja/spresense/specifications), [HDR対応イメージセンサー搭載——ソニー「SPRESENSE」向け「HDRカメラボード」発売](https://fabcross.jp/news/2022/20220427_sonyspresense_hdrcameraboard.html) それとも`RAW画像`と言われるものでしょうか？ [spresesnse cameraモジュールからRAW画像の取得](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/63695/26370) 公開資料等に使われているのと同じ言葉を使わないと正確・迅速な回答を得ることは難しいのでは？ 他にこんな記事も[SpresenseでのRGB565フォーマットによる高解像度画像の取得ができない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/86599/26370), [カラー画像認識...](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/56380/26370), [Spresenseで高解像度...](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/65268/26370)

Comment: 先のコメントで紹介した製品情報にはHDRカメラボードの出力フォーマットに`RAW`は無いし、HDRでは無いカメラボードでも紹介したQ&A記事で誤記と回答されたり現在の製品情報に記載が無いので、ハードウェアの機能や設定等は無いのでは？ HDRカメラで`raw画像`が取得出来るという資料やWeb上の記事などがあるならそれらの情報や紹介リンクを質問記事に追記してみてはどうでしょう？ あるいはSonyではない別のメーカー/ベンダーのHDRカメラなのかもしれませんが、その場合はそのベンダーや型番の詳細を追記してください。

Comment: HDRカメラということでRAW画像が取得できるものと考えてしまっていました。

Comment: 接続・制御インタフェースが`I2C`だと制限があるのでは？ USBで接続・制御するUVCインタフェースのものがあるならばできるかもしれませんね。ただし出来たとしても別に紹介した記事のようにメモリサイズが不足するかも。